# Need help setting up Mink Extension for Behat

Tags: behat, mink

I am new to using the Mink Extension for Behat V3.0.15. The Mink version number is 1.7.0.

I have set up the extension using the following configuration on my behat.yml file

```
default:
extensions:
   Behat\MinkExtension:
  base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
  goutte: ~
```

I keep on getting this error..

[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
  Indentation problem at line 4 (near "  base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org").

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue. There was a space indenting issue . It was a space indenting issue. Here is the configuration settings that worked...

```
default:
 extensions:
   Behat\MinkExtension:
    base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
    goutte: ~
```